# Morphia: Index on collection using deprecated configuration options (Composite key Index)

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

Recently we have upgraded from Morphia 0.99 to 1.2.x and MongoDB to 3.2.

After that we are seeing a lot of WARNING messages while using collection objects, which are having composite key indexes.

Sample warning is as follows:

> WARNING: This index on 'RowData' is
>   using deprecated configuration options.  Please update to use the
>   fields value on @Index:
>   @org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Index(unique=false, dropDups=false,
>   name=, background=false, expireAfterSeconds=-1, value=resultSetId,
>   rowSequence, disableValidation=false, sparse=false, fields=[],
>   options=@org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.IndexOptions(unique=false,
>   dropDups=false, name=, background=false, expireAfterSeconds=-1,
>   disableValidation=false, language=, languageOverride=, sparse=false))

Index tag on Object is as follows:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
@Indexes({@Index("resultSetId, rowSequence")})
public class RowData implements Transportable { ... }
```

Is there any way to suppress the warning messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to suppress the warning, it's there to tell you the configuration you are using will not be supported soon.

try this one instead

```
@Indexes({ 
    @Index(fields = {@Field(value = "resultSetId"), @Field("rowSequence")})
})
```

**Note on IndexOptions:**
If migrating from older Index syntax to latest, either leave the IndexOptions part altogether (like above) or make sure you are setting the same options as-is on your collection before change. Otherwise, you will get an exception related to IndexOptions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I missed this change in syntax. Just being cautious, I will apply the updated syntax and see if any regression is there.

Comment: Solved the problem. I am updating your answer to add an additional not on IndexOptions.